# I am getting NSDate null while converting from string?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
    NSString * string=@"20-02-2014";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
```

I am getting date = null, Please help me to find the issue ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NSDateFormatter` is wrong, you have `MM-dd` but your string is `dd-mm`.
Change it to:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

That should help.

Comment: yes I was wrong - But now I get the date = 2014-02-23 00:00:00 +0000     How to make it as date = 2014-02-23

Comment: The date is like that, this is a NSDate format. Are you asking how to format NSDate to string like: 2014-02-23?

Answer (score -3):

if you are using datePicker then try this code:

```
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];


[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd, YYYY"];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSString *dateselected=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter       stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
[datelabel setText:dateselected];
[formatter release];
[datePicker release];
```

Comment: What does this do differently from @Nithin M Keloth's code?

Comment: this does not cover the parsing problems OP has. And there is no indication that OP is using a date picker.